# Custom Column header in MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I am trying to fill MDX query result to a datatable. Query is generating dynamically. When i fill datatable column header like ***[Dim Date].[Day].[Day]***. I need it ***Log Date***.

Is there any way to change column header ? I mean, in TSQL we using

```
select firstName [User] from users
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the SQL side like this:

```
WITH mdx as (
    <your MDX query>
    )
SELECT [[Dim Date]].[Day]].[Day]]] as [Log Date]
       ...
  FROM mdx
```

The escaping rules of square brackets make this a bit strange: You have to double all closing square brackets.

You can get this slightly more easy, avoiding the square bracket quoting in the rename action by using

```
WITH mdx([Log Date], ...) as (
    <your MDX query>
    )
SELECT [Log Date], ...
  FROM mdx
```

enumerating the desired column names after the CTE name "mdx".